# OnClick se ejecuta al cargar pagina en ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

Buen día tengo este problema desde ayer. Al poner onclick en un boton y llamar una funcion interna de la clase, se ejecuta solo el onclick. Digamos qeu tendria que ejecutarse al darle click y que me muestre por consola el 
"asdasdd" pero no hay caso, siempre lo hace al recargar la página.

Cualquier recomendacion es bienvenida.

Dejo mi archivo de la clase en ReactJs

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Mother from './Mother.js';

class Tabla extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  click(){
    //const mother = new Mother();
    //mother.addMother(id);
    console.log("asdasdasd");
  }

  verificar(){

  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <img height="250" src={this.props.obj.img} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <div className="producto">
                <div className="container">
                  <h5>{this.props.obj.modelo}</h5>
                  <div className="container">
                  <span className="badge badge-success" id="precio" >$ {this.props.obj.precio}</span>
                </div>
                  <button onClick={this.click()} className="btn btn-danger mt-3">Agregar al carro </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default Tabla;
```

Comment: No se nada de react, pero al parecer el código se ejecuta por que la función render 'activa' todas las acciones que estén contenidas de la manera `{ accion() }`. Intenta quitando los paréntesis asi `{ this.click }`

Comment: Mas informacion: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Efectivamente eran los parentesis, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es necesario quitar los paréntesis de `this.click`

Answer (score 1):

En el caso de que ocupes los paréntesis, agregar un arrow function `onClick={ () => this.click() }`

Comment: Esto parece relamente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]